# How do I get all the text within a tag using a Nokogiri CSS selector?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to extract text from an HTML page using Nokogiri. I am using CSS selectors to extract the text.

I know the `text` method is used to extract the text inside a particular tag but it only gives the text that is an immediate child of the tag.

How do I get all the text in a tag including the text that may be inside any tags that are nested within the said tag?

```
<td>
<div>
some text
</div>
<div>
more text
</div>
</td>
```

How do I get all the text in the `<td>` tags inside `<td>` since `text` will not return anything and it is not known beforehand how many tags are going to be there inside `<td>`.

Comment: `text` returns all the text contained within a particular node. As [the docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#text-instance_method) say, it "Returns the content for this Node".

Comment: Sorry I was doing something wrong I guess. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can simply call the `#text` method of the target element and it will include all child text nodes:

```ruby
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(your_html_snippet)
str = doc.css('td').text
str # => "\n\nsome text\n\n\nmore text\n\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`str = doc.css('td').content`

this will get you all the text at all the levels of nesting